# Maven- War encapsulated in ear is not updating

Tags: maven

I want to create an ear including a war. I have used packaging as ear and used both war plugin and ear plugin. 
But whenever I build using clean install, it takes the war from the m2 repository and create an ear with it. It does not creates a new war while packaging the ear.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: Show your pom files and how you called Maven furthermore how does your directory layout looks like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add WAR inside EAR with Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5167024/how-to-add-war-inside-ear-with-maven)